# JESS -> How to check the type of a variable and test it?

Tags: types, numbers, integer, jess

I have a assignment in JESS (Java Expert System Shell) and I'm having some trouble with it.

I'm trying to check if a certain variable (read from the keyboard) is a positive integer (I have already managed to check if it is positive) but I can't find a way (or a function) to check if the variable is an integer/number.

I tried the functions *intergerp* and *numberp* but these don't seem to work.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: I answered, but I suspect there will be more to this. If you modify your question to explain more why `integerp` doesn't do what you want, I can elaborate in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`integerp` is, indeed, the way to check if something is an integer, as you can see in the transcript below.

```
Jess> (bind ?x (read))
1
1
Jess> (integerp ?x)
TRUE
Jess> (bind ?y (read))
foo
foo
Jess> (integerp ?y)
FALSE
Jess> (bind ?z (read))
1.1
1.1
Jess> (integerp ?z)
FALSE
```

Comment: Thank you Mr. Friedman-Hill, I'll have a better look at it and see why my rule isn't working :)

Comment: (defrule  error
        (declare (auto-focus TRUE))
        ?f <- (kb ?x)
        (test (numberp ?x))
        =>
        (printout t "Please insert an integer" crlf))

(defrule  error
        (declare (auto-focus TRUE))
        ?f <- (kb ?x)
        (numberp ?x)
        =>
        (printout t "Please insert an integer" crlf))

There are two different tries of the rule I'm trying to do. I read a certain value from keyboard in the MAIN module and if this variable is not an integer then this rule will be triggered and it will ask the user to insert the value again.

Comment: The first one is correct, but the second one is wrong; the left-hand-sides of rules contain patterns, not function calls ("test" counts as a pattern here.) But the first one should work fine, assuming that something is asserting a `kb` fact with one item in it, the value read from the keyboard. So maybe you should show me where that fact comes from.

Comment: (defrule init
        =>
        (printout t "Insert function number: " crlf)
        (bind ?fun (read))
                (if (= ?fun 1) then (focus Somar))
                (if (= ?fun 2) then (focus Subtrair))
                (if (= ?fun 3) then (focus Quadrado))
        (printout t "Insert integer: " crlf)
        (assert (kb (read))))

I just removed some (printout)'s to make it easier to read as it doesn't change rule behaviour.

Comment: It took me much too long to see this, but the problem is in the other rule -- your rule matches when `(test (integerp ?x))` is true, but you want to print the message when `(test (integerp ?x))` is *false*, and that must be the problem you're seeing. Just change the pattern to reverse the logical sense of the expression -- i.e., `(test (not (integerp ?x)))`